# How to know which method to use to work out hand probabilities in Texas Hold'Em Poker?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, games, game-theory

So I just asked earlier about how to calculate the probability of a starting pair making quads (four of a kind) on the flop and was informed that it's a hypergeometric distribution and essentially it's just (48C1)/(50C3) = 0.25% or 408 to 1.

However, when calculating the probability of a starting pair making three of a kind on the flop, it's just 1-((48/50)x(47/49)x(46/48)) = 12% or 7.5 to 1.

Also, I read that if you have a flush draw after the flop (two suited cards in your hand and two of the same suit in the flop), you calculate this as follows: there are 9 outs (9 other cards of the same suit left in the deck of cards) and 47 cards remaining within the deck which leaves 38 cards not of the same suit, and thus 9 x 38 = 342 possible combinations of the outs and remaining other cards. So 342 / 47C2 = 32% or 2.16 to 1 chance of getting one of those cards.

So, my question is essentially how does one know when the calculation is such as that used to determine the probability of a pair making 3 of a kind on the flop, or a pair making 4 of a kind on the flop, or making a flush after the flop? The reason I was failing earlier (relates to my first question posted) to calculate the probability of a starting pair making four of a kind on the flop is because I was trying to use a calculation similar to that used for calculating the three of a kind. So, how to know when to use which calculation?